# server side code crashing only IE?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Strange issue: PHP runs a nested foreach that generates a string (basically a calendar that shows people's holidays).

This string goes in `$data['grid']` and sent to the view. `var_dump` shows: `string(188263)`

The string is printed out fine in the webpage when viewed with FF and Chrome but for some reason when viewing with IE6, 8 and 9 (not tested in 7) it crashes the browser every single time; it hangs and nothing ever appears on screen.

IE can show the string when it's printed out in the controller, so before it's passed to the view.

This works fine in IE:

```
print $str; die;
$data['grid'] = $str;
$this->load->view('conge', $data);
```

This crashes IE:

```
//print $str; die;
$data['grid'] = $str;
$this->load->view('conge', $data);
```

The total "weight" of the page is 192KB and there is no JS running. It feels like a PHP / memory problem but the fact that the "bug" only exist in IE makes little sense.

Any ideas how this can be debugged?

EDIT: When I saved the rendered output from FF in to a static HTML file and load that in IE it sill crashes. The string was printed out without line breaks (loooong) but when I add \n the problem persists. Anyway, one step closer.

EDIT2: It seems to be due to errors in the HTML markup that cause IE to crash (?!). Case closed!

Comment: Save the html from one of the 'working' browsers to a file and try loading that file in IE. If it still crashes, then it's not PHP - it'd be something in the HTML that's trigger IE to barf.

Comment: have you compared the HTTP response between the two? What exactly is transmitted? Use Firebug or Fiddler to capture the two responses and compare them.

Comment: I think we need some more information about what is actually being output.  Whatever it is, it's probably messing with how IE renders the page in a way that crashes it.

Comment: Is `$grid` printed in a table? It's a table you coded or generated by the table helper? I think the problem lies there and the browser difficulties in rendering it

Comment: HTML output please. Ooh, and response headers.

Comment: try adding \r\n instead of \n and tell us what happens... so, it is not a PHP / Code Igniter issue

Comment: Would you please post a self-accepted answer or delete this if it is resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serverside code cannot crash the browser.

The HTML file generated can crash the browser so you need to examine the outputted HTML carefully.

Point the w3c validation service at the URL and see what it comes back with.

If that yields no results start commenting out large section of the header, then the body etc until you get a successful render then you can investigate a small section of code instead.

Btw I'm assuming 192k includes images, CSS etc else that's a monster HTML file!